# Accessing AWS resources securely using the AWS SDK for .NET

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to access an AWS S3 bucket and DynamoDB securely using user pools and identity pools. I can log in a user:

```
        public static async Task<bool> SimpleLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        bool loginSuccess = false;
        string accessToken;
        UserCredentials user1 = new UserCredentials() { Username = username, Password = password };

        //taken from this article https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/cognito-authentication-extension.html

        var creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(IAMAccessID, IAMSecretID);

        AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider =
            new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(creds, RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);

        CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolID, clientID, provider);
        CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(user1.Username, clientID, userPool, provider);
        InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
        {
            Password = user1.Password
        };

        try
        {
            AuthFlowResponse authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (authResponse.AuthenticationResult != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("User successfully authenticated.");
                loginSuccess = true;

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error in authentication process.");
                loginSuccess = false;
            }
        }

        catch (Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.NotAuthorizedException nae)
        {
            //bad username or password
            loginSuccess = false;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //any other exception
        }

        return loginSuccess;

    }
```

But, as I understand it, the next step is to use the access token returned to access and identity pool so that I can then access the S3 bucket and DynamoDB. I cannot find any examples that do this.

This code creates Cognito credentials and attempts to log into the bucket:

```
 CognitoAWSCredentials c = new CognitoAWSCredentials(identityPoolID, RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);

        using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(c, RegionEndpoint.EUWest2))
        {
            var dir = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, "recordings", "924f22fb-2694-4fce-b85a-47b1c59b8466");

            foreach (IS3FileSystemInfo file in dir.GetFileSystemInfos())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(file.Name);
                Debug.WriteLine(file.Extension);
                Debug.WriteLine(file.LastWriteTime);
            }

            ListBucketsResponse response =
                await client.ListBucketsAsync(new ListBucketsRequest()).ConfigureAwait(false);

            foreach (S3Bucket bucket in response.Buckets)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(bucket.BucketName);
            }
        }
```

But, I'm having two problems with this. First, I'm getting a 400 error when creating the S3DirectoryInfo object, and secondly when I'm creating the identity pool credentials, they're not asking for an access token, which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

Let me address your comments one at a time:

1. When you are trying to run the examples, do you pull the entire example application from GitHub or do you just copy and paste from the Code Library? The code library focuses on the code that actually performs the API call. To successfully run an example, you have to get the whole thing from GitHub.
2. Instantiating a client object for any of the examples can be done with no parameters if the default user has been set up properly. Setting up the credentials properly is described in GitHub at the language level.
3. The Cognito_MVP namespace is the namespace of the basic scenario that shows how to use Cognito. Again, to find it, you have to look at the entire example on GitHub rather than the excerpt that is published in the code catalog.

Comment: thanks Irene - I'll try it again!

Comment: I've got the examples, thanks, and they now work, but I might be completely missing the point. I thought I could log in as an IAM user to authenticate a user from a Cognito Userpool and then use an access key/secret key to access S3/DynamoDB resources, but I'm now thinking that's not how it works.

Comment: this is a JS example of what I'm trying to do:

AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({ IdentityPoolId: "Our Identity Pool Id, found in Cognito menu" })
var s3 = new AWS.S3()
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket_name', Key: 'file_name'}
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params)

the credentials are set by an identityPoolID and used to authenticate in S3.

Answer (score 1):

"I cannot find any examples that do this"

Looks like you want an example that shows how to use temp creds to access AWS Services. One way is to use IAM and STS vs Cognito.

There is an example that performs these tasks using IAM and STS:

- Create a user who has no permissions.
- Create a role that grants permission to list Amazon S3 buckets for the account.
- Add a policy to let the user assume the role.
- Assume the role and list Amazon S3 buckets using temporary credentials.
- Delete the policy, role, and user.

This use case is documented in the new **AWS Code Library** in different programming langauges, including C#. The Code Library has 100s of **unit tested** examples that work.

[image]

You can access this use case in C# here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/iam_example_iam_Scenario_CreateUserAssumeRole_section.html

**Cognito example**

If you want to use Cognito to get an athent token, the code lib also has that example in C#. See this URL:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cognito-identity-provider_example_cognito-identity-provider_Scenario_SignUpUserWithMfa_section.html

**UPDATE ON THE .NET MVP CODE**

When you stated it did not run, I tested it in Visual Studio 2022. You can get all of the code, project files, etc from Github here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/dotnetv3/Cognito

Once you get this code from Github, open it, follow the instructions, specify the pool id and client id that the program requires, it runs fine. See this illustration.

[image]

**NOTE**: As I stated, every single program in the code library has gone through extensive unit testing to ensure they work.

Comment: These are usesful examples. If you are writing code to enable user access to a website you need Cognito but if you are just making API calls, IAM would be enough.

Comment: Thanks, "The Code Library has 100s of unit tested examples that work." I haven't been able to find a single example that works yet, but I'll follow your links and see how I get on. I've now found a JS example that successfully does exactly what I need, but the AWSSDK doesn't appear to do it the same way, so I can't translate.

Comment: I'm following the example and getting the message: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 instance metadata service.

I think it's because when the example creates a service client, it's only passed the region, so there's no associated account:

 var client = new AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(Region);

Comment: in the example you give, there's a namespace, Cognito_MVP and I don't know where to get this. There's an object called CognitoMethods which doesn't exist. All these examples are so difficult to follow because of these omissions.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a single example that works yet -- they are pieces of code. We did not want to repeat setup code in all of these examples. EACH EXAMPLE has a note that states -- 

"There's more on GitHub. Find the complete example and learn how to set up and run in the AWS Code Examples Repository." Once you read the content on Github, setup the DEV environment, set your CREDS,  and get the full program that includes main() - they will run

Comment: @NickWright The 'associated account' should be configured using [aws shared credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/overview.html). This is a prerequisite step before using the AWS CLI or running the SDK examples.

Comment: thanks for your help, both, will give it another go!

Comment: Working through the example, I've now logged in successfully as a cognito user. When I call InitiateAuthAsync on line 143of CognitoMethods, I get a response with an AuthenticationResult and reading the docs, this means I have no challenges remaining. How do I then use this result to access S3/DynamoDB resources?